# Kendo UI Grid Localization

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code that takes language preferences from user input and adjust the culture and the language. Everything works fine except the add new record on the toolbar will only get translated if the page id refreshed.
here is my code so far help please!!

```
 //get the saved language from localstorage

 $.getScript(baseUrl + currentLang + ".min.js", function () {
        kendo.culture(currentLang)
        createGrid();
    });

    $("#lang").on('change', function (e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        currentLang = valueSelected
        $.getScript(baseUrl + currentLang + ".min.js", function () {
            kendo.culture(currentLang)
            createGrid();
        });

    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Supersnake   I have one add new record button on my toolbar and it only gets translated only if i reload or refresh the page. while the rest of my components like the edit and cancel buttons get translated with out reloading the page